# What is the best way to obfuscate python file and then convert it into an exe?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyarmor

I converted my python script into an executable but, as I heard, it is not very difficult to read the source code from an executable file, so there is a risk of reverse engineering. I tried to obfuscate my code with pyarmor and it works well, but when I convert it to an exe with pyinstaller it doesn't work. Also tried to use pyarmor to obfuscate and turn into exe at the same time, but my project is large and I get this error from pyarmor:

> ERROR    Too big code object, the limitation is 32768 bytes in trial version

I want to know if there is an effective method to do this, before I purchase pyarmor license.

Comment: the risk really depends, obvs it won't convert an obfuscated code because it is no more python, is it? I mean what are they gonna reverse engineer? attack your server? well then protect the server if you have one, server won't be laying around user's files so they can't really get to that. Take user's file and attack them??? if they can access their files why even bother with this? create a copy and distribute it? that can be done without knowing anything about your code, just use their own and change name and logo to match yours

Comment: Why it doesnt work when you convert it into .exe ? Can you share the error

Comment: already found the solution. libraries caused an error. I wrote all necessary imports in the obfuscated version and it worked